# Unable to set Pin Change Interrupt on ATmega328p

Tags: avr, interrupts, register, atmega328p

so I am working on learning some AVR programming with the ATmega328p.  I am trying to set up a pin change interrupt and this is the code I am running.  However, the interrupt never seems to trigger.  Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Is there some way I can test this outside of using a board, like in simulation?  I am using Atmel Studio.

Thanks!

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define ON_B0 PORTB |= (1 << PORTB0)
#define OFF_B0 PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB0)
#define TOGGLE_B0 PINB |= (1 << PINB0)

ISR(PCINT1_vect)
{
    // Check if pin B1 is low)
    if ( !( PINB & (1 << PINB1) ) )
    {
        ON_B0;
    }
    else
    {
        OFF_B0;
    }   
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= ( 1 << DDB0 );
    DDRB &= ~( 1 << DDB1 );

    PCMSK0 |= ( 1 << PCINT1);
    PCICR |= ( 1 << PCIE0);

    sei();


    while (1) 
    {
        PORTB |= ( 1 << PORTB1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt get that the code inside the infinite while loop. Are you setting a port pin that you've config'd as input? Did you try without that line (i.e. with only the infinite while loop)? One more thing (just to check that the ISR is triggered): Toggle the pin (by XORing with 1) instead of checking whether it is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have an ISR on the `PCINT1` vector, but the vector for PORTB pin changes is `PCINT0`. Uninitialized vectors jump to address 0, so the MCU resets when a pin change interrupt occurs on PORTB.

This is an easy mistake to make because `PCINT1` is the designation of **pin** PB1 for pin change, and *also* the name of the **vector** for pin change interrupts on PORTC (thanks Atmel!).

You need to change `ISR(PCINT1_vect)` to `ISR(PCINT0_vect)`.

> Is there some way I can test this outside of using a board, like in
>   simulation?

Yes (this is how I found the error in your code). In AVR simulator you can simulate a pin change by clicking on the pin to toggle it, then follow the resulting code execution with 'step into' (F11). View disassembler to step through the machine code one instruction at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> the interrupt never seems to trigger.

You probably want to assure yourself that the ist isn't firing. Otherwise you are solving A non existent problem.

Secondly read the datasheet to see how you clear the point flag.

Having simpler code helps too.